# Docker: Restart Container only on reboot?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I've got a docker-compose service that needs to be restarted only when docker or the system restarts. The service should not restart when an error occurred or the service completes. The flags `--restart unless-stopped` or `--restart always` doesn't work for me because with these flags the service is going to restart, too, when an error occurres.

Comment: Not possible out of the box.

Comment: I've the same question. When my system reboots the containers don't start. The docker documentation says to use the restart_policy but that mainly deals with container crashes. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question.  I tried using the docker compose restart_policy and found that it did not work.

services:
  hello:
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: ...

WARNING: Some services (hello) use the 'deploy' key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support 'deploy' configuration - use docker stack deploy to deploy to a swarm.

See the answer to here [Docker: Restart Container only on reboot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58026334/docker-restart-container-only-on-reboot)

So, I then considered doing something in the Dockerfile but the docs suggest setting up an external process to restart containers, using the same command we use to start them normally.
See https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

> If restart policies don’t suit your needs, such as when processes
>   outside Docker depend on Docker containers, you can use a process
>   manager such as upstart, systemd, or supervisor instead.